# "Doubly Lipschitz" function composition

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $U$ and $V$ be Euclidean spaces. Let $X\subseteq U$ and $Y\subseteq V$ be open, bounded subsets.

Let $G:=\operatorname{BLip}(X\times Y,U)$ be the (Banach) space of bounded Lipschitz functions from $X\times Y$ to $U$ with norm given by the $\max$ of the $\sup$ norm and the Lipschitz modulus. (See e.g. Chapter 8 of "Lipschitz Functions" by Stefan Cobzas, Radu Miculescu and Adriana Nicolae.)

Let $H\subseteq G$ be open and suppose:

1. For all $h\in H$, $h(X\times Y)\subseteq X$.
2. There exists $C>0$ such that for all $g_1,g_2,h_1,h_2\in H$, all $x_1,x_2\in X$ and all $y_1,y_2,z\in Y$:

$$\begin{align} & \|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)+g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\| \\
& \le C \max{\{\|g_1-g_2\|,\|h_1-h_2\|\}} \max{\{\|x_1-x_2\|,\|y_1-y_2\|\}}. \end{align}$$

**Can $H$ be non-empty? What is the largest possible $H$ with this property (in some loose sense)? Could $H=\{g\in G|g(X\times Y)\subseteq X\}$?**

---

**Note 1**: In any case for all $g_1,g_2,h_1,h_2\in G$, all $x_1,x_2\in X$ and all $y_1,y_2,z\in Y$:

$$\begin{align} & \|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)+g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\| \\
& \le \|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)\| + \|g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\| \\
& \le [\|g_1\| \|h_1\| + \|g_2\| \|h_2\|]\max{\{\|x_1-x_2\|,\|y_1-y_2\|\}} \end{align}$$

and:

$$\begin{align} & \|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)+g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\| \\
& \le { \|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)-g_1(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)+g_1(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\| \\
+ \|g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)+g_2(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)\| } \\
& \le { \|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)-g_1(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\|+\|g_1(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\| \\
+ \|g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)\|+\|g_2(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)\| } \\
& \le [\|g_1\|+\|g_2\|] \|h_1 - h_2\| + 2\|g_1-g_2\| \\
& \le [2+\|g_1\|+\|g_2\|] \max{\{\|g_1-g_2\|,\|h_1-h_2\|\}}. \end{align}$$

---

**Note 2**: Suppose that $g_1,g_2,h_1,h_2\in G\cap B(X\times Y,U)$, where $B(X\times Y,U)$ is the space of bounded *linear* operators from $X\times Y$ to $U$.

Then for all $x_1,x_2\in X$ and all $y_1,y_2,z\in Y$:

$$\begin{align}
& g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)+g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z) \\
& = g_1(h_1(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2),0)-g_2(h_2(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2),0) \\
& = g_1((h_1-h_2)(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2),0)+(g_1-g_2)(h_2(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2),0).
\end{align}$$

So:

$$\begin{align}
& \|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)+g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\| \\
& \le [\|g_1\|\|h_1-h_2\|+\|g_1-g_2\|\|h_2\|]\max{\{\|x_1-x_2\|,\|y_1-y_2\|\}}.
\end{align}$$

Thus by symmetry:

$$\begin{align}
& \|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)+g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\| \\
& \le {\min{\{\|g_1\|+\|h_2\|,\|g_2\|+\|h_1\|\}} \cdot \\ \max{\{\|g_1-g_2\|,\|h_1-h_2\|\}}\max{\{\|x_1-x_2\|,\|y_1-y_2\|\}}.}
\end{align}$$

Hence, were it not for the requirement that $H$ be open, $H$ could contain $G\cap B(X\times Y,U)$.

---

**Note 3**: A sufficient assumption.

Suppose that $g_1,g_2,h_1,h_2\in G$.

Define $f:X\times Y\times Y\rightarrow U$ by:

$$f(x,y,z)=g_1(h_1(x,y),z)-g_1(h_2(x,y),z)$$

for all $x\in X$, $y,z\in Y$. So for all $x\in X$, $y,z\in Y$:

$$\|f(x,y,z)\|\le \|g_1\|\|(h_1-h_2)(x,y)\|\le \|g_1\|\|h_1-h_2\|.$$

**Assumption:** Suppose that there exists $K>0$ such that for all $x_1,x_2\in X$ and all $y_1,y_2,z\in Y$:

$$\|f(x_1,y_1,z)-f(x_2,y_2,z)\|\le K \|g_1\|\|h_1-h_2\|\max{\{\|x_1-x_2\|,\|y_1-y_2\|\}}.$$

Then as for all $x_1,x_2\in X$ and all $y_1,y_2,z\in Y$:

$$\begin{align}
& g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)+g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z) \\
& = (g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z))-(g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)-g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)) \\
& = {(g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z))-(g_1(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)-g_1(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)) \\ +(g_1(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)-g_1(h_2(x_2,y_2),z))-(g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)-g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z))} \\
& = {(g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)-g_1(h_2(x_1,y_1),z))-(g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)) \\ +((g_1-g_2)(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)-(g_1-g_2)(h_2(x_2,y_2),z))} \\
& = {(f(x_1,y_1,z)-f(x_2,y_2,z)) + ((g_1-g_2)(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)-(g_1-g_2)(h_2(x_2,y_2),z))},
\end{align}$$

we have that:

$$\begin{align}
& \|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)+g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\| \\
& \le \|f(x_1,y_1,z)-f(x_2,y_2,z)\| + \|(g_1-g_2)(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)-(g_1-g_2)(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)\| \\
& \le [K\|g_1\|\|h_1-h_2\| + \|g_1-g_2\|\|h_2\|]\max{\{\|x_1-x_2\|,\|y_1-y_2\|\}} \\
& \le [K\|g_1\| + \|h_2\|]\max{\{\|g_1-g_2\|,\|h_1-h_2\|\}}\max{\{\|x_1-x_2\|,\|y_1-y_2\|\}},
\end{align}$$

as required.

**However**, our assumption is false for general $g_1,h_1,h_2\in G$.

To see this, take $h_1(x,y)=x-c_1$, $h_2(x,y)=x-c_2$, $g_1(x,y)=\max{\{0,x\}}$ for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$. Then $\|h_1-h_2\|=|c_1-c_2|$, but $\|f(x_1,y_1,z)-f(x_2,y_2,z)\|=\|x_1-x_2\|$ for $x_1,x_2\in(\min{\{c_1,c_2\}},\max{\{c_1,c_2\}})$.

---

**Note 4**: The answer to the final question appears to be "no" in general.

Much as before, take $h_1(x,y)=x-c_1$, $h_2(x,y)=x-c_2$, $g_1(x,y)=g_2(x,y)=\max{\{0,x\}}$ for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$. Then $\max{\{\|g_1-g_2\|,\|h_1-h_2\|\}}=|c_1-c_2|$, but $\|g_1(h_1(x_1,y_1),z)+g_2(h_2(x_2,y_2),z)-g_1(h_1(x_2,y_2),z)-g_2(h_2(x_1,y_1),z)\|=\|x_1-x_2\|$ for $x_1,x_2\in(\min{\{c_1,c_2\}},\max{\{c_1,c_2\}})$.

---

**Note 5**: This question relates to my previous question here: ["Doubly Lipschitz" functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112437/doubly-lipschitz-functions)

The older question can be viewed as a simplification of this one, but does not directly give an answer. (I was hoping for inspiration for the harder question. I now think I'm better off just asking the real question!)